# Big Query Extracting date from string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

### | orders |

|sold [2022-06-09 to 2022-06-17] |

What I am trying to get is

| orders | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sold [2022-06-09 to 2022-06-17] | 2022-06-09 | 2022-06-17 |

```
select
    Orders, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Orders,r'([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])') dates
from table
```

But BQ gives me the result in one row then split into 2 rows

| Row | Orders | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text with dates | 2022-06-09 |
|  |  | 2022-09-17 |

when exported to csv it is

| Orders | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| text with dates | [2022-06-09,2022-06-27] |

I have tried to select left/right to get the fields I want but get an array error from Big Query

Pointers Appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select Orders, dates[offset(0)] as date1, dates[offset(1)] as date2
from table, 
UNNEST([struct(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Orders,r'([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])') as dates)])
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]